# Execute code with strange * symbol from package: catchfilebetweentags

Tags: errors, symbols

I would like to execute a specific command from the CTAN package CatchFileBetweenTags (see https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/catchfilebetweentags/catchfilebetweentags.pdf) which features a strange ``∗" symbol.

If I execute the command

```latex
\ExecuteMetaData [filename]{tag}
```

there is no issue. However, no matter what combinations -- with blanks, without blanks --- I try, the command

```latex
\ExecuteMetaData * [filename]{tag}
```

does not seem to work.

One error I get is that: ``Argument of \UTFviii@three@octets has an extra }. \ExecuteMetaData�".

Comment: Oh you mean you are typing that in source? The command is supposed to be a normal latex star form with an ascii `*` not `∗`

Comment: Sorry, yes, tried all variants here too. It simply seems to me as if the package only knew the unstarred versions..

Comment: no it is a latex star form the markup has to use `*`  (U+002a), (the same as `\section*` or `\begin{tabular*}` etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}

\ExecuteMetaData ∗ [filename]{tag}
\end{document}
```

produces the error shown

```
! Argument of \UTFviii@three@octets has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 \ExecuteMetaData �
                      �� [filename]{tag}
?
```

as the LaTex `*`form of a command must use  `*` (U+002A) not other asterisk symbols such as `∗` (U+2217 )

This version has no error (although does nothing useful in this form)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}

\ExecuteMetaData * [filename]{tag}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this --- but this does not work for me... I mean \section*{...} works, etc. -- just this does not work...

Comment: @WernerEinstein f you use `*` you will not get the UTF-8 parse error so that is basically the answer to the question as posted. If you have an example of `\ExecuteMetaData*` that is not working then that is an unrelated issue, you should make a complete small example test document and post a new question. The error in this question is not related to the behaviour of the catchfile command at all, it is a syntax error parsing the star-form before that command is really executed.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I am might misunderstand something about the ExectureMetaData * command in general